# Swift UIPicker input to label text

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uipickerview

What I am trying to is have the user scroll the picker and where the user stops at in the label have a description of the item in the picker. I have included all of my code to this point. I only have about 2 months of Swift coding on iOS under my belt, so I am sure there are a lot of concepts I am missing here. Thank you for your time.

```
import UIKit

class Weapons: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var WeaponPicker: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var WeaponLabel: UILabel!

var pickerData: [String] = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    WeaponPicker.delegate = self

    pickerData = ["Great Sword", "Switch Axe", "Hammer", "Lance", "Bow", "Light Bowgun"]
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return pickerData.count
}
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return pickerData[row]
}
}
```

Comment: You need to implement the `pickerView(didSelectRow:)` delegate method -https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipickerviewdelegate/1614371-pickerview

Answer (score 1):

Just implement `didSelectRow`

Then you can do something like

```
WeaponLabel.text = pickerData[row]
```

EDIT: Adding an explanation.

If you want to show a description based on the weapon, you can do this:

Make a struct for weapon and description:

```
struct weaponObject {
    var name: String
    var description: String
}
```

Declare an array of type weaponObject:

```
var pickerData = [weaponObject]()
```

In `viewDidLoad`:

```
let names = ["name1", "name2"]
let descriptions = ["description1", "description2"]

for (name, description) in zip(names, descriptions) {
    pickerData.append(weaponObject(name: name, description: description))
}
```

In `didSelectRow`:

```
WeaponLabel.text = pickerData[row].description
```

In `titleForRow`:

```
return pickerData[row].name
```

Comment: how would someone go about populating the label with data to correspond with the item selected in the picker?

Comment: The easiest way to do this, in my opinion, is to use a struct. I'll add the explanation to my answer.